# Corona Zoom in and zoom back to normal state

Tags: image, zooming, coronasdk

In Cocos2d I was able to zoom out / scale my scene down, i.e. 0.2, and when i want it restored i could change to 1.

In Corona, if I scale to 0.2, and try and rescale to 1, it keeps it as 0.2, so essentially it takes the arg and scales the current image / displayGroup to that.

So to determine normal scale I need to calculate over scale factor?

Essentially I want to double tap too zoom out, and double tap to return to normal state. But there is no way to hold my previous state and restore that I can figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as follows. This will work.

1: Create a scaleFactor:

```
  local scale_factor = 0.2;
```

2: When you want to zoom out, do :

```
  Your_object:scale(scale_factor,scale_factor)
```

3: When you want to zoom in, do :

```
  Your_object:scale(1/scale_factor,1/scale_factor)
```

Keep coding... :)

Comment: Thanks, did similar thing and with some tweaking got to working well.